# Autofill password in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

I have to do a lot of loggin in on webpages and I like that firefox autofills in my passwords, once it knows them...

How can I achieve the same for google chrome?

I have read [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/45320/can-i-force-google-chrome-to-remember-passwords), installed the `autofill=true` extension but that does not do the job...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use **[KeePass](http://keepass.info/index.html)** Password Safe?

it works with Google Chrome. much safer than storing passwords in a browser.

Edit:

KeePass features includes **Auto-Type, Global Auto-Type Hot Key and Drag&Drop**

- KeePass can minimize itself and type the information of the currently selected entry into dialogs, webforms, etc. Of course, the typing-sequence is 100% user-customizable, read the documentation file for more.
- KeePass features a global auto-type hot key. When KeePass is running in the background (with opened database) and you press the hot key, it looks up the correct entry and executes its auto-type sequence.
- All fields, title, username, password, URL and notes can be drag&dropped into other windows.

*KeePass is free open source software, a portable version is available.*

Comment: Does this solve my problem? I don't have a security issue, as I am testing webapps with dummy passwords. I just don't want to fill it in everytime...

Comment: yes, edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

I have found that Chrome will not remember and autofill usernames/passwords for forms that do not have the action attribute set (making the action default to the same page as the form).

Once the action attribute is explicitly specified in the form (even if it's the same page as the form), Chrome will autofill the username and password.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a secure password manager for Google Chrome, then I recommend the LastPass extension. However, if you're looking for a general purpose automatic form filler, then consider my [Autofill extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nlmmgnhgdeffjkdckmikfpnddkbbfkkk).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to be sure that you are logged into Google Chrome first. In the upper right hand corner  click on the three horizontal bars. Under Downloads there is a space which tells you if you are logged in as yourself. If you are not signed in, click on that and log in under that setting. Once logged in Chrome should remember your history and logins on any computer you log into Chrome on. It will sync it over the different computers or devices.