# How can I force chrome to remember my passwords?

Tags: google-chrome, password-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I force Google Chrome to remember passwords?](https://superuser.com/questions/45320/can-i-force-google-chrome-to-remember-passwords)

On most sites, chrome has stored my passwords, however, on one particular site (paypal.com) I can't get it to ask if I want to remember the password.

Is there a way to manually do this or force chrome to save the password?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://superuser.com/q/45320/88853

Answer (score 9):

I have been aggravated for quite a while because Chrome did not remember username and password at a website I frequently use. The website is not one that should be highly concerned about security such as a financial site like PayPal. Searching for solutions I found one comment that it may be that the website redirects so fast that the Chrome prompt to save is overwritten (or some other mechanism may be repressing or causing the Chrome save password prompt to go away).

I just found a solution to this that makes me very happy. I go into tools / options / personal stuff and click on "Import data from another browser" then select Firefox from the dropdown menu, and uncheck everything except "Saved Passwords" then click "Import" and VOILA the saved username and password I had for the website in Firefox is now in Chrome. :-)

Comment: This answer makes no sense. The only way to save a password in Chrome is to save it in Firefox and then import it from Firefox?

Answer (score 5):

Follow the directions on [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/62980/how-to-force-your-browser-to-remember-passwords/) article and you should be able to save your password. It basically uses a JavaScript code to force the browser to prompt for remembering the password.

You can use this add-on: [Autocomplete = on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ecpgkdflcnofdbbkiggklcfmgbnbabhh). However, one of the comments on the add-on says it doesn't work for PayPal's website. It may be worthwhile testing that out for yourself.

**Disclaimer:** In most cases sites that do not allow you to save the password usually do it for security reasons, which is probably true for PayPal as well. So it may not be a good idea to save your password for such sites, putting your personal information at risk.

Comment: Thanks Mahendru! I can save the paypal password on Safari for Mac OSX Lion. Not sure why other browsers (on PC) do not allow it.

Comment: No problem. Thats why I recommended testing it. Just because the add-on did not work for one user, doesn't mean that it doesn't work at all. Please accept the answer if it worked for you. Thanks!

Comment: The link specified here is now inaccessible.

Comment: And the first part of this answer is wrong, too, as even that article recognises that "we could not get it to work within Chrome despite the success message that autocomplete was enabled."

Comment: @SMeznaric this link seems to do the same as the original one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions (at least in 2021 when it was available, so I archived it at https://archive.is/EBPlH)

Comment: I just tested this, and unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work anymore and/or doesn't work with Paypal, as OP's question pertains to.