# Chrome phpmyadmin Saved Password not coming up anymore

Tags: passwords, phpmyadmin, google-chrome

I'm using Chrome with 2 installs of phpmyadmin (3.3.2deb1 and 2.11.8.1deb5+lenny8). Since about 3 weeks ago, chrome does not remember the saved password anymore and doesn't prompt to save it. Both installs are on default http connections and use the MySQL password - session ba

Other browsers do and save the password. I have checked:

- chrome saved passwords (empty)
- chrome don't save password list (empty)

Comment: I have this problem with few other websites as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several solutions to this one problem.

The thread [Can I force Google Chrome to remember passwords?](https://superuser.com/questions/45320/can-i-force-google-chrome-to-remember-passwords) gives this advice :

> Use the [autocomplete=on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocomplete-on/gdhbgagnmhdafendedikgjimegoipbnk) extension. It changes 'autocomplete=off'
>   to 'autocomplete=on' in web pages, so your passwords will be
>   remembered.

The thread [Chrome doesnt ask to save passwords](http://groups.google.com/group/google-chrome-help-troubleshooting/browse_thread/thread/d4fb1d2320e9cd33/953f243364e486fb) says :

> Go to `C:\Documents and Settings\YOUR PROFILE\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
>   Make sure chrome is closed
>   Delete the file named `Web Data` (or make a backup)
>   Restart Chrome
>
> Once you restart, chrome should automatically create the same "Web
>   Data" file.
>   The only problem is that you'll have to save all the passwords again.

(This advice is evidently for XP, other operating systems will have this file elsewhere.)

The thread [Google Chrome Save Password Problem?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101223015831AAYvw7r) advices a last-ditch effort of importing the passwords from Firefox.

Comment: Thank you, your first answer hits the nail on the head and solves my original problem.
The second answer is what I sort of excluded as a valid answer for purposes of the bounty - given that I had no other responses for ages I assume it may be the "best answer" as well.