# How to force Chrome to remember a password?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, password-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I force Google Chrome to remember passwords?](https://superuser.com/questions/45320/can-i-force-google-chrome-to-remember-passwords)

Chrome is not trying to remember a password on web.ebuddy.com

Is there a way to force Chrome to remember a password for this website?

The attribute `autocomplete` is not present.

Comment: does https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/forms.html#remember_password work?

Comment: If you enable chrome://flags/#enable-password-force-saving then you can right click on the password field and instruct the browser to store it.

Comment: @DanielF It's now renamed to chrome://flags/#PasswordForceSaving (Chrome 65)

Comment: @Dan Thanks! I've been searching for it lately and thought they removed it. That's great news.

Comment: @DanielF Your comment is by far the most useful info here, thanks! You just got my +1 at https://superuser.com/a/1182335/460458

Comment: @Dan Now there is no such flag either.

Comment: Very often if on Chrome-on-PC doesn't offer to remember password, if you access the website from Chrome-on-Mobile, then it does offer to remember. And if you have the Chrome browsers in sync, saving on one equals saving on all.

Answer (score 12):

Chrome has the [*Autocomplete On* extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocomplete-on/kkffidhhikbopjomeeaihconieppiaan?hl=en) to work around the sites that code autocomplete off.

Comment: this did not help with the right site

Comment: Still works! Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 6):

Have you already had a look at this thread: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/chrome/_neIKCmoHb4/7VezgIG0sBEJ

It lists reasons chrome might not offer to remember a password - I checked and the site does not specify "autocomplete=off" so you can ignore that. However, make sure to follow the instructions to check that you did not tell Chrome not to remember the password.

> Henry B. said:
>
> There are several reasons why Google Chrome won't offer
>   to remember your password:
>
> 1. You've previously told Chrome to never save you password for that site.
>
> On Windows and Linux, you can resolve this by following the steps in
>   the referenced help center article [1]
>
> On Mac, there is currently no way to browse for and delete exceptions,
>   so using the "Chrome Application Menu > Clear Browsing Data..." tool,
>   selecting only the "Passwords" checkbox, selecting "Everything" for
>   the time period, then clicking "Clear browsing data" should cause
>   Chrome to re-prompt to save passwords for all sites.  We realize this
>   is not ideal and have an open bug to add a way to browse passwords and
>   remove exceptions on Mac [2]
>
> 2. The site uses specifies that the browser should not remember passwords
>
> Some sites, often banking sites (and Mint.com, @ddddod), specify that
>   browsers should not remember passwords by marking the field with
>   "autocomplete=off".  For these sites, Chrome will not offer to save
>   your password.  We're considering adding an indicator so that you can
>   more easily figure out which sites cause this issue.  I've also heard
>   of extensions that work around this issue, but that method is
>   unsupported.
>
> 3. The site submits the login form in unusual ways
>
> There is no one way for websites to log users into a site.  Sometimes
>   sites use unusual techniques that confuse Chrome's logic for
>   determining that a login was submitted.  We're working on making
>   Chrome better at working around these issues, but in the meantime,
>   please file a bug so we can track these sites.