# How to override a website blocking autocomplete on forms (Google Chrome)?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, webforms

Is there currently a way in Chrome to stop websites from blocking autocompletion of forms?

I'm open to any suggestions my skills would cover, so if there is no addon which does the job, I'll have a go at editing Chrome's hidden settings or the Windows registry. Writing an addon myself is beyond my powers, unfortunately.

I know Firefox would do a better job at respecting my form-filling preferences, but it really is getting too laggy on my old computer. I'd like to find a Chrome-based solution, if one exists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I force Google Chrome to remember passwords?](http://superuser.com/questions/45320/can-i-force-google-chrome-to-remember-passwords)

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ecpgkdflcnofdbbkiggklcfmgbnbabhh

Comment: You can't - the webpage will control it

Answer (score 3):

The Chrome extension [Autocomplete=on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocomplete-on/gdhbgagnmhdafendedikgjimegoipbnk?hl=en) will do this.

Comment: This has a bug and long not updated.. A new one here; [Force Autocomplete](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/piechbhjioolbecaioglhamjjjkmbchj/publish-accepted?hl=en-US)

Comment: @AbdessamadIdrissi: Your link is borked, it's the link to publish the extension, not to view/install it. Use this one instead: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/force-autocomplete/piechbhjioolbecaioglhamjjjkmbchj?hl=en-US. The extension looks quite outdated and non-working anymore though :-(

Comment: This extension worked for me: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocomplete-on/kkffidhhikbopjomeeaihconieppiaan