# Password memorization and autocomplete heuristics in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, password-management, forms

What are Chrome's heuristics to decide to save login form data and autocomplete them on the next visit?

If Chrome isn't saving the credentials on a particular form, what could the reasons be? I know that:

- the username and password fields [must have `autocomplete="on"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398763/how-does-browser-know-when-to-prompt-user-to-save-password/12852166#12852166);
- the form [must have `method="POST"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715000/enabling-browsers-form-auto-filling).

Experimentally, this is not enough: I have a login page (private, sorry, but the gist of the code is below) that meets both criteria and where the credentials aren't autocompleted.

---

Here's my specific problem. I've solved it another way (by installing [Autofill](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autofill/nlmmgnhgdeffjkdckmikfpnddkbbfkkk?hl=en) and making it enter my credentials on the form), but I'd still like to know why Chrome isn't offering to save the credentials.

A website (not written by me, and not publicly accessible) requires a username and password. It uses a fairly standard-looking (to my uninformed eyes) form, which looks like this (I've omitted a lot of nested `<div>` and whatnot, and attributes and functions shown here as `fooXXX` were renamed by me).

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="default.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Username:</td>
      <td><input name="foo$name" type="text" id="foo_name" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="fooFunction()" style="width:175px;" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
      <td><input name="foo@pass" type="password" id="foo_pass" tabindex="2" value="" autocomplete="off" style="width:175px;" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I want my browser to remember my credentials for this site. The feature is enabled in the browser, but there's something peculiar about this site that causes both Firefox and Chrome not to offer to remember the name and password.

I wrote a userscript (Greasemonkey script in Firefox, unpacked extension in Chrome) to change `autocomplete="off"` to `autocomplete="on"`:

```
document.querySelector("#foo_user").setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
document.querySelector("#foo_pass").setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
```

In Firefox, this has the desired effect: Firefox offers to remember the password, and the next time I visit the login page my credentials are autofilled.

No such luck in Chrome (27.0.1453.93, Linux). I don't get prompted to remember the password and don't get a history for the username field. I have confirmed that the script is executed by inspecting the `input` elements, they do show `autocomplete="on"`.

I tried adding these lines to my userscript, but they don't improve the situation.

```
document.querySelector("#foo_user").removeAttribute("onkeyup");
document.querySelector("#foo_pass").removeAttribute("value");
```

How do Chrome's heuristics differ from Firefox, and how do I get it to remember my credentials?

Comment: What does `fooFunction()` do? Might it be changing the `autocomplete` attribute back on? What happens if you change your userscript to `document.querySelector("#foo_user").removeAttribute("autocomplete");` (and the same for `#foo_pass`)? Finally, can you change the time at which the userscript runs? It might be that Chrome has already evaluated whether or not to autocomplete a field **before** your userscript has run.

Comment: @MattDMo `fooFunction` only applies some capitalization rules to the username (don't ask me why — the username is case-insensitive server-side!). In any case removing the `onkeyup` attribute didn't help. I also tried removing the `autocomplete` attribute altogether (did that first, in fact), without success. I have no idea how I would change the time at which the userscript runs.

Comment: Based on the comments on this question http://superuser.com/questions/457310/how-to-override-a-website-blocking-autocomplete-on-forms-google-chrome it doesn't seem like you can get Google Chrome to do what you want. But there isn't any explanation on that question, so I don't know what Chrome's actual criteria are, which is what you wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [autocomplete=on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocomplete-on/ecpgkdflcnofdbbkiggklcfmgbnbabhh) extension.

> Changes 'autocomplete=off' to 'autocomplete=on' in web pages, so your
>   passwords will be remembered.

Comment: This looks like it could work - hopefully it gets executed before the userscript, and the value isn't dynamically changed back later in the page loading process.

Comment: As expected, it makes no difference. I'm already doing the same thing this extension does. @MattDMo This is Chrome, userscript = extension.

Answer (score 1):

I found a flag that seems to solve the problem of autocomplete while looking for new flags.
In chrome://flags, there's a flag named "Enable login detection". Flip that to "Disabled", and it should (at least until the experiment is removed) solve your issue.
(On Chrome for iOS, this flag does not exist! So, on that platform, you're stuck!)
And as for what the answer is to *what* Google uses, my bet is that it uses intents like those for the Omnibox, where you can see history, but I'm not sure of that!
Regards, Mac