# How to add saved password to Chrome manully

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

Chrome doesn't offer to save passwords at some sites, is there any way to add the passwords manully?

Comment: There are easier ways to do this that don't involve having to install an entirely different browser. http://superuser.com/questions/45320/can-i-force-google-chrome-to-remember-passwords and https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocomplete-on/ecpgkdflcnofdbbkiggklcfmgbnbabhh#detail/autocomplete-on/ecpgkdflcnofdbbkiggklcfmgbnbabhh

Comment: Not an answer but you can use lastpass..

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your link, but autocomplete-on extensions doesn't work for me on a few sites.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Firefox;
2. Install "Saved Password Editor" plugin for Firefox;
3. Manully add passwords you wanted;
4. Use Chrome - Settings - Import bookmarks and settings, import from Firefox and uncheck items except "Saved passwords", then click Import, Done!

Comment: Asked: 4 mins ago. Answered: 4 mins ago. The answer isn't even good... And it's a duplicate

Comment: @chipperyman573 While I agree with the last two points, please realize that there is a reason there is a "Answer your own question" check box at the bottom of the "Ask a Question Page".

Comment: Only if you find your answer *after* you ask your question

Comment: @chipperyman573 That is [false](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer): "Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. *If you have a question that you already know the answer to*, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site."

Comment: Oh, TIL. But still, bad answer.

Comment: @chipperyman573 But I think this is the only way not involving an chrome extension. And I believe there are many users like me, who doesn't want to add a extension _permanently_, but is ok with another browser _temporarily_.

Comment: LassPass and autocomplete extensions are good solutions, but I just want to use chrome's internal feature.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following extension:

[LastPass extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lastpass/hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd)

This extension can be used on other browsers also

Comment: Thanks but LastPass is a little heavey for me, I just want to use chrome's own feature:-)